# PDF to SWF convert by cmd in php

Tags: flash, swfloader, pdf2swf

hi i use this code to convert pdf to the swf i have pdf2swf.exe file in my site in the local server and i want to move pdf called 1.pdf to that pdf2swf.exe to be convert using command line buts it is not work i don't know why that its the code `enter code here`

```
<?php 

$software_path ="C:\\wamp\www\wellelafa\SWFTools\pdf2swf" ;
$pdf_path ="C:\\wamp\www\wellelafa\SWFTools\1.pdf" ;
$argument = "-o";

$swf_output ="C:\\wamp\www\wellelafa\1.swf" ;

$cmd ="$software_path $pdf_path $argument $swf_output";

$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");


$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C $cmd ", 0, true); 


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 

$software_path ="C:\\wamp\www\wellelafa\SWFTools\pdf2swf.exe" ;

$pdf_path ="C:\\wamp\www\wellelafa\SWFTools\1.pdf" ;

$swf_output ="C:\\wamp\www\wellelafa\1.swf" ;

$cmd =$software_path . " -b " .  $pdf_path . " -o "  .  $swf_output";

exec($cmd);

?>
```